# Functor instance of State

Tags: haskell

```
instance Functor (State s) where
  fmap f (State g) = State $ \s0 -> 
      let (a, s1) = g s0
      in (f a, s1)
```

It is implementation of `Functor` for `State`. I cannot understand how does it work? Especially, `g` is used as it would be a function but on my eye it is not a function. It is just object ( perhaps function) but I cannot understand why it is function. After all, it should be some state so it can for example `Int`

Please make clear.

Comment: Usually you have `State s a = State (s -> (s, a))` so indeed `g` is a function with type `s -> (s, a)` (i.e. it takes a state and produces a result (`a` in this case) and a new state (`s1`)). This `Functor` instance simply applies `f` to the result of the computation before returning the value.

Comment: The name state is indeed confusing and the state is a monad itself. What is a monad is something which access and or modify a state.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like your state type looks like:

```
data State s a = State (s -> (a ,s))
```

so your `fmap` function should have type:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> (State s a) -> (State s b)
```

when you match on the input state value in

```
fmap f (State g) = State $ \s0 ->
```

`g` is a function `s -> (a, s)` and you need to construct one of type `s -> (b, s)`.

```
(a, s1) = g s0
```

applies the input state to the existing stateful computation, binding `a` to the result and `s1` to the new state. It then applies `f` to `a` to obtain the mapped result value in

```
(f a, s1)
```

while the state returned from `g` is unchanged.

Comment: *"while the state is unchanged."* is somewhat ambiguous. "while the state originally returned by `g` is unchanged" could be better.